# How to detect current page media type in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with input fields. I want to do hide the all 0 values text fields when page is in media type print.

I have tried in [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/KAsq6/). But this is works both in screen mode and print model.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="screen">some screen</div>
<div class="print">some print</div>
<input type='text' name='' id='1' class='' value='0'/>
<input type='text' name='' id='2' class='' value='5'/>
<button>Print</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      if ( $(this).val() == 0 ){
        $(this).hide()
      }     
    })
})
```

**CSS:**

```
@media print{
    .screen{
      display:none;
    }

    .print{
      display:block;  
    }
}

@media screen{
    .screen{
      display:block        
    }

    .print{
      display:none;   
    }
}
```

If I detect the current page's media type. I can finished it. Unfortunately I couldn't get the right code.

I also tried [jmediatype](http://code.google.com/p/jmediatype/), but there is no download option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to hide the fields with `value="0"`, you can do this with just CSS:

```
@media print {
    input[value="0"] {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to give those elements a class that only gets hidden by the print stylesheet:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').filter(function() {
        return parseInt(this.value, 10) == 0;
    }).addClass('print-hidden');
});
```

And use a style like this:

```
@media print {
    .print-hidden {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a CSS file for media print only which contain:

```
.empty
{
    display: none;
}
```

include this CSS file in your mage, only for **media print**

Add a listener on the button for the click event. This listener will add empty CSS class for input with empty value.

```
$("ID_OF_YOUR_BUTTON").click(function(mouseEvent) {

    $("input[type=text]").each(function(index, element) {

        if ($(element).val().length == 0)
            $(element).addClass("empty");

    });
});
```

For the media screen, this class will do nothing, but for the media print it will change the display to **none**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the media type of a particular stylesheet you can do this in jQuery:

```
var media = $('link[href$="styles.css"]').attr('media');
```

You'd have to separate your stylesheets and load them in the markup with the media attribute instead of using the media queries in one file.